# One person from a party is selected at random

Tags: probability, word-problem

Here is the question:

> John invites 12 friends to a dinner party, half of whom are men.
> Exactly one man and one woman are bringing desserts. If one person
> from this group is selected at random, what is the probability that it
> is a woman, or a man who is not bringing a dessert?

I'm not a native speaker, how should I understand *"a woman, or a man who is not bringing a dessert"* please?

Should it be construed

> (1) *a man who is not bringing a dessert or a woman*

or

> (2) *a woman who is not bringing a dessert or a man who is not
> bringing a dessert*

?

Because apparently the answer is different from each other and if I'm not wrong, (1) is 11/12 and (2) is 10/12.

By the way, how would this sentence "*a woman who is not bringing a dessert or a man who is not bringing a dessert*" be written if it is not "*a woman, or a man who is not bringing a dessert*"?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: That is an unfortunate aspect of language... parentheses to emphasize groupings are helpful when writing symbolic expressions but they aren't often used with words for that purpose.  Personally, I would expect more people to interpret "*a woman, or a man who is not bringing a dessert*" with the inclusion of the comma as either a woman who is or is not bringing a dessert --- or --- a man who is not bringing a dessert.

Comment: That said... you adeptly identified that there is the possibility of confusion here and were able to find the correct answers for both interpretations.  In a real life scenario, you are the one writing the statements and so can write and interpret the statements as you intend... or in an educational scenario you are *encouraged* to ask for clarification on a question like this if it were during a testing scenario.  The purpose of a course in probability is to understand the *mathematics* involved.  The grammar isn't generally meant to be a particular concern.

Comment: Thank you for your acute insight, the question is from the GRE prep and this exam is infamous for such tricky and twisted language. I hope such ordeal is not occurred during my test then.

Comment: I added the `word-problem` tag, since the question is more about the interpretation of the words in the problem than probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is about to calculate the probability of the person selected is either a woman, or a man without bringing dessert.

Interprete it to logic language, it should be:
$$P(woman\bigcup man without dessert)=P(woman)+P(man without dessert)$$

So what you need to do is simple arithmetic, $1/2 + 5/12=11/12$

Btw, since there is a comma at the end of woman, it means that we should consider this sentence separately. Your assumption(2) is making sense if and only if the comma doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by JMoravitz, you have correctly identified the answers for both, so well done, and usually you would ask for clarification in a test or something like that.

In my opinion, I would interpret "a woman, or a man who is not bringing a dessert" as (2) a woman who is not bringing a dessert or a man who is not bringing a dessert.

But again, don't stress as this type of ambiguity in a test is rare. The comma is ambiguous, and I might be wrong. In an actual exam, ask for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! Unfortunately the question's answer is (1). Mine was (2) like yours but it was wrong according to the book.

Comment: JMoravitz actually cleaved to interpretation (1)—which is what I would do, as well.  (Actually, I'm now realizing that the wording in the OP of (1) could be interpreted also as "a man who is bringing neither a dessert nor a woman," along with a host of other interpretations.  Language is tricky!)

Comment: Ah, it seems I misinterpreted JMoravitz's interpretation!

Comment: @Tui, don't stress on this, usually you would ask for clarification.

Comment: Gill: Even in the GRE exam? that's good to know, thank you so much! And thank you @BrianTung for your clarify as well as adding the tag!

Comment: @Tui - I am not familiar with the GRE exam. I suggest you may ask about it on a different site on stack exchange for proper advice for specifically GRE.

Comment: @Tui: I doubt you would be able to ask for that clarification on the GRE.  Well, you could ask, but I doubt you'd get a helpful answer.  I don't think the proctor (for in-person tests) is in general selected for their knowledge in the particular topic.